# QuerySet throwing error when calling mode_to_dict

Tags: django, django-models

Getting below error when Calling API from Postman. Is it models problem?

**Error**

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
Internal Server Error: /candidates/CandidateSummary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 511, in dispatch
    self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 423, in finalize_response
    assert isinstance(response, HttpResponseBase), (
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
[10/Mar/2022 20:21:23] "GET /candidates/CandidateSummary HTTP/1.1" 500 77831
Unauthorized: /candidates/CandidateSummary
[10/Mar/2022 20:21:39] "GET /candidates/CandidateSummary HTTP/1.1" 401 58
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
Internal Server Error: /candidates/CandidateSummary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-**

packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 511, in dispatch
        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 423, in finalize_response
        assert isinstance(response, HttpResponseBase), (
    AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

**

Models.py

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    candidateid = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    Account = models.ForeignKey(Account,blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")

    PrimaryPhone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True,null=True) # validators should be a list
    SecondaryPhone =  models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True,null=True) # validators should be a list
    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.Name
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated 
from candidates import models
from django.forms import model_to_dict
from django.http import JsonResponse


class CandidateSummary(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            candidatesobj = models.CustomFields.objects.filter(id=1)
            candidatesobj = model_to_dict(candidatesobj)
            return Response({"Status":"Success","candidates":candidatesobj})
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

The same code works for other apps however the issue seems to be with this app.

Sorry but will add some random text, sf is not allowing to post the question without more text.

Effective supplier evaluation

These metrics are reflected financially. This starts with recognizing the actual transport spend vs budget. However, financial analytics can be taken much deeper, looking at the annual spend per lane, the percentage of transport costs taken up by fuel surcharges or annual carrier accessorial fees

Comment: Are you sure in the other apps you are not using `.get(...)` iso `.filter(...)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes,I'm using .get and .filter in other apps, they are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try .get() or .first(), because .filter() returns queryset object, which is kind of a list of objects. But model_to_dict() only works with single object (instance). Use either this one,

```
candidatesobj = models.CustomFields.objects.filter(id=1).first()
candidatesobj = model_to_dict(candidatesobj)
```

or, this one.

```
candidatesobj = models.CustomFields.objects.get(id=1)
candidatesobj = model_to_dict(candidatesobj)
```